# php mvc structure with database variables

Tags: php, mongodb, naming-conventions, variable-assignment, nosql

I am *experimenting* on a **sort-of** MVC structure PHP project.

Suppose I have a model for users, that looks like this: (I am using **pseudocode**)

```
function addUser($name, $surname) {
  mysql_query("insert into users name=$name surname=$surname");
  return true;
}

function getUser($id) {
  $object = mysql_query("select from users where id=$id limit 1");
  return $object;
}
```

and in my controller I have:

```
$user = getUser("foo");
```

so I can access user information to be printed out easily like this:

```
$name = $user["name"];
```

so far, so easy. The problem which I suppose I might face if I keep going this way is that, if one day I will have to change the column 'name' into say, just 'n', all the components that are getting the object returned by getUser() will have to be modified to reflect that change.

How does it work in this cases to avoid such problem?

P.S. I know this is not exactly MVC but a VMC-ish structure; it's just to get the idea on how to do it. If I made any mistake explaining please be patient and don't freak out: we are humans and not robots and most importantly we are here to LEARN.

---

why I said that is that I am actually not using mysql but mongodb, which as the object structure like this: {name:"foo", surname:"fuu"} that is basically repeated for every object so I thought that to save space in the db I might just decide to change it one day from 'name' to just 'n', saving 3 ascii chars per object! It's out of the scope of the question but I think you understand now why I need to use this.

Comment: Generally column names don't change. But when they do it's inevitable that you have to make changes in your code. Because some parts simply reflect your database design. Alternatively, you can always *name* your columns in your `SELECT` statement. Like: `SELECT n AS name ...` That way you won't have to update code parts.

Comment: Your P.S. has touched me! Implement Classes that wrap your tables (or logical units), implement getters that abstract actual column names.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also, which has nothing to do with MVC. I'm removing the tag.

Comment: Please note that the solution *Khez* gives means you still have to tell what properties of your class maps to what columns in your DB. So there is still some dependancy. Although, when a column name changes that means you'll only have to change the part where you specify what property maps to what column. So basically you'll only have to apply a change in one location. Which is the best OO method for your case. Usually ORMs do this kind of stuff for you already, mapping classes to tables.

Comment: @tereško I agree! mysql should not be learnt or otherwise use from now on!

Comment: But this has nothing to do with the question actually, since OP is using MongoDB, not MySQL. The question should be just removed.

Comment: Also, what is "VMC-ish" ? You cannot just make up acronyms. They have no meaning then.

Comment: @tereško why so upset? first, the database doesn't have anything to do with the object returned, because I have simplified the code, it doesn't matter what's inside the getUser() function: what is returned is always an array object as I described, like `$user['name']`. Secondly, haven't ever heard of procedural mvc? as stated in the answer it is an **experiment** and secondly you are not an encyclopedia, you do now own the secrets of being and I can make up any acronym I want.

Comment: but you do own the admin hammer. fail at life.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use getters and setters in your model class:

```
<?php
class User {

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->n= $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->n;
    }
}
```

Or you can use the `__get` and `__set` magic functions:

```
<?php
class User {

    public function __get($key) {
        if ($key == 'name') {
            return $this->n;
        }
        else {
            return $this->$key;
        }
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        if ($key == 'name') {
            $this->n = $value;
        }
        else {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

However, you really *shouldn’t* be changing database column names, and definitely *not* to single letters like “n”. That ambiguity is just **asking** for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You want to *decouple* the structure of the database from the variable/index/property names you use in the rest of the code, having an insulating layer between these two parts of your system which translates between them. This is best done using objects:

```
class User {

    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->setName($name);
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

The function which fetches data from the database now doesn't return that data as is, depending on what format the database feels like returning the data today, but it returns an instance of the specific, defined object `User`:

```
function getUser() {
    $data = query('SELECT ...');
    return new User($data['n']);
}
```

If you change column names in the database, you only have to change code in this layer which fetches from the database, not everywhere throughout your code base. You can make this work without objects, using functions which create array structures of a defined format instead. But it's hard to beat the *type safety* an object affords you.

Comment: Somebody having too many votes he needs to get rid of? *Some* comment on any of the downvoted answer would be nice.

Comment: I Feel the same! Might it be something to do with the system layout preference MVC? I've not looked into it before. Do you know what it is? lol

Comment: blame it on teresko, he got it all against me for God knows what reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few things that I would like to suggest with your code. But as for the changing of column name why would you have to change it? If you did yes you'd have to correct for query. My a little worried about the sanitation of your functions as well as the use of mySQL which has been made dropped in PHP 5.0 +. You may want to look at mySQLi which is the replacing equivalent sort of. I'm not so brilliant at procedural based code so forgive me if I make any errors.

With your functions, there is no need to return the true; or return the mysql_query. These are complied without the return. Also Within your queries it's best to capitalise key words such as: `SELECT, FROM, WHERE, INSERT INTO, LIMIT`. Your selecting columns should always be declared as well, even if your selecting all of them. Query string example:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '{$id}'"//Variables should be entered in this way
//I don\'t know why they just do lol 
"SELECT id,name FROM table WHERE table.id = '{$id}'"//This will only return the id and name from the table named table
```

So for your script I'd recommended a mysqli procedual style. Here's the procedual style:

```
$DBH = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','optional Database selection');
mysqli_select_db($DBH,'selection of the data can be done this way also');
mysqli_prepare($DBH,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?");//note the question mark instead of your $id variable.
mysqli_bind_param($DBH,'i',$id);//this replaces your question mark with the variable $id. This is a lot more sanitised that your example.
//bind_param() expects 3 parameters. first the database, second the variables datatype
// 'iiss' would be int int string string third comes your vars 
mysqli_execute($DBH);
mysqli_bind_results($tableID,$tableName,$otherColumns);//your columns will be returned in order. Selecting * will return all columns. Selecting id,name will return only id and name column.
while(myslqi_fetch_result($DBH)){
    //this is basically saying while there are results fro the database.
    echo $tableID.' '.$tableName.' '.$otherColumns;
}
```

Now I'd also recommend an OOP (Object Orientated Program) for the way you've structured your functions. That would look a little like this:

```
Class users{
    private $DBH;//makes sure our database handler is secure 
    public function __construct(){
        //public so that this function is ran at the start of the class
        $this->DBH;//how to access your variables and functions in OOP in other words
        //$addUser->DBH; which would be private and inaccessible. 
        $this->DBH = new mysqli('local','user','pass','database');
    }
    public function addUser($name,$surname){
        $query = $this->DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL,?,?');
        $query->bind_param('ss',$name,$surname);
        $query->execute();
        //you can also run a check query returned true function :)
    }
    public function returnUser($id){
        $data = array();
        $query = $this->DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?');
        $query->bind_param('i',$id);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($ID,$name,$surname,$other);
        while($query->fetch_result()){
            $data[] = array('ID'=>$ID,'name'=>$name,'surname'=>$surname,'other'=>$other);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
$userHandler = new users(); //adding an instance of the class users();
$usersInfo = $userHander->returnUser($id);//userinfo will now contain an array of arrays of users that have an id of $id. Depends how you use it :p
```

sorry if I've done too much in one go and or you already knew and I'm just being a dick lol 
I hope I've help with the mysqli queries and structure of your program

Answer (score 0):

> why I said that is that I am actually not using mysql but mongodb, which as the object structure like this: {name:"foo", surname:"fuu"} that is basically repeated for every object so I thought that to save space in the db I might just decide to change it one day from 'name' to just 'n', saving 3 ascii chars per object!

Wow a whole three ASCII characters.

Sorry it is just some people really take this whole storage thing of MongoDB way too far.

It does not decrease the size of your index and nor does it stop fragmentation, in fact due to odd document sizes it might increase that fact (non-standard names for fields causing irregular sizing of documents). The only real benefit you will see is maybe a few bytes if your system is hard done by in terms of Virtual Memory when MongoDB comes to mmap your files.

Seriously just save yourself the hassle already, I doubt you will ever reach a point where your collection will contain so many documents that this micro-optmisation will actually have an effect; I mean we are talking about billions of documents maybe on a single shard here (why would you do that??).

Fact is most field shortening has occured because people have this strange thought that for some reason a couple of bytes (like the difference between `username` and `n`) will have some profound effect on storage and memory usage and index size (MongoDB does not store the key name in the index...) and all that fakey stuff when it doesn't really.

If you were to name a field `my_awesome_really_long_field_that_is_good` then yes, there would easily be a case to shorten your fields but the difference between a normally, sanely, named field and a single letter field is, for most parts, nout.

The use case for single letter fields whittles down to so little that I doubt you will ever reach a point where it would be beneficial for you to use it and even if you did you would be handling too much data for a ORM like Doctrine or your own to do this in a performant manner so this question is enert there anyway.

So I am not joking, don't bother with this. You will be wasting more resources in your PHP app than you will be saving on the database end.

Comment: I think you're asking another question

Comment: @m4t1t0 I think you need to read the quote I took from the question and that this is a mongodb question if you read it carefully and that the OP is most likely doing aliasing cos he has read some where that shrinking `name` to `n` helps. That is what I answer, the question.

Comment: Maybe some one can describe why this was downvoted?

Comment: Ok,sorry, he has updated the question